# how to perform a segue

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, storyboard

I would like implement a button to show another view.  I have defined the destination ViewController in Storyboard & created a segue (of type push) and gave it an identifier.

In my root view controller

some method ...

```
        UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(showDetailView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and

```
- (IBAction)showDetailView:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowDetail" sender:sender];
}
```

however it doesn't do anything.  I hear a Segue is an object. do I need to have a reference to it / synthesize it in my root view controller class?  Any tip would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Edit:

Make sure your root view controller is embedded in a navigation controller. if it isn't, select your view controller in the storyboard designer and choose Editor->Embed In->Navigation Controller in the menu.

Original:

Double-check the Identifier (storyboard-code) and try setting `sender` to `self`. If that doesn't work you can create a Segue object yourself in code.

Comment: ok I tried setting `sender` to `self` but didn't work.  How can I create the Segue object? (or refer to the Segue I created in Storyboard?)

Comment: do I need to add navigation bar/controller or is there some protocol I need to conform to in order to use Segue?

Comment: did you embed your root view controller in a navigation controller?.. this is required for a "push"-segue to work..

Comment: Thanks a bunch, that did the trick!  is there a way to hide the navigation bar in the root ViewController? (I need more screen space)

Comment: Set `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;` in your `viewWillAppear:` method

Comment: Thanks! This hides the navigation bar for the destination view also. Is there a way to set hidden for root but show for the 2nd screen? :(

Comment: do the opposite in viewWillAppear in your 2'nd view controller